# Angular swiperJS slideChange event does not work when initializing initialSlide to a value other than zero

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, swiper.js

i added a method called when slideChange,this method only logs the active index,and it works perfect.

but then i added:

[initialSlide]="2"

,and when loading the app ,i received the error :

"Cannot read property of undefined(reading 'activeIndex'"..
And if i changed it to :

[initialSlide]="0"

i got no error

this is the the HTML code:

```
    <swiper
    #swipper
    [lazy]="true"
    [preloadImages]="false"
    [autoHeight]="true"
    loadPrevNext="true"
    loadPrevNextAmount="1"
    [slidesPerView]="1"
    [spaceBetween]="0"
    [initialSlide]="2"
    (swiper)="onSwiper($event)"
    (slideChange)="onSlideChange()"
    [navigation]="true"
    dir="rtl"
  >
    <ng-template swiperSlide let-data> <app-p1></app-p1></ng-template>
    <ng-template swiperSlide let-data> <app-p2></app-p2></ng-template>
    <ng-template swiperSlide let-data> <app-p3></app-p3></ng-template>
    <ng-template swiperSlide let-data> <app-p4></app-p4></ng-template>
    <ng-template swiperSlide let-data> <app-p5></app-p5></ng-template>
  </swiper>
```

and this is the ts code:

@ViewChild('swipper') private swipperREF: any;

and this is the loging function:

```
onSlideChange() {
console.log(this.swipperREF.swiperRef.activeIndex);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

try using `(slidechange)="onSlideChange($event)"` event instead of (slideChange).
You should get a custom event with active index at position event.detail[0].activeIndex.

You probably don't get error for doing initialSlide=0 cuz its default.